# lua - screen limit for characters

Tags: lua, love2d

**I have a problem where my character keeps going out of my screen.**
How do I fix this problem? I know I need to put in a function to prevent the character from going out of the screen and managed to do it on the radius of the circle.

```
    if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
        player.x = player.x + 4
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
        player.x = player.x - 4
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
        player.y = player.y - 4
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
        player.y = player.y + 4
    end

    if AABB(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h, target.x,    target.y, target.raduis) then
        score = score + 1
        target.x = math.random(target.raduis, love.graphics.getWidth() - target.raduis)
        target.y = math.random(target.raduis, love.graphics.getHeight()- 100)
    end
```

Comment: Preventing a character from going "out of screen" is as simple as clamping their X and Y coordinates to screen coordinates (perhaps plus/minus character size). What is `AABB`, why are you randomizing and using circles there?

Comment: Don't move the player down if they're already at the bottom.

Comment: @LMD My guess is that AABB checks collision with target, increases the score and starts the next "level" by randomizing the targets position. I agree, clamping seems the most accurate and easiest solution here.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what the "character" is, so im going to do both the player and the target

if you want the character to not go off screen, try:

```
if player.x < 0 then
    player.x = 0
elseif player.x + player.w > love.graphics.getWidth() then
    player.x = love.graphics.getWidth() - player.w
end
if player.y < 0 then
    player.y = 0
elseif player.y + player.h > love.graphics.getHeight() then
    player.y = love.graphics.getHeight() - player.h
end
```

if you want the target to stay on screen, try:

```
if AABB(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h, target.x,    target.y, 
target.raduis) then
    score = score + 1
    target.x = math.random(0 + target.raduis, love.graphics.getWidth() - target.raduis)
    target.y = math.random(0 + target.raduis, love.graphics.getHeight() - target.raduis)
end
```

hopefully this helps